# continue searching for string in Table until no more results are found then go to next search term

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have a working code that allows me to find a string in a table and returns the value of an adjacent cell (adopted from a different code) and writes it to an array

```
Dim raArray As Range
Dim iC As Long

  For iC = 1 To 51 'The array is a 2D Array: arrAllYield(5,50)

     Set raArray = wksA.Cells.Find(What:=arrAllYield(1, iC - 1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
      :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
      False, SearchFormat:=False)

    If raArray Is Nothing Then
       MsgBox ("Not found")

    Else
      arrAllYield(3, iC - 1) = wksA.Cells(raArray.Row, raArray.Column + 12) 
      arrAllYield(4, iC - 1) = wksA.Cells(raArray.Row, raArray.Column + 26)         
   
    End If

  Next iC
```

Since there are multiple instances of that string in that table, I don't want to move on to the next search term in the array when one such string is found.

The search terms are all found in a single column ("E")

Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To stop after a match is found, you can use `Exit For` as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/exit-statement

So your example code would look like this

```
Dim raArray As Range
Dim iC As Long

For iC = 1 To 51 'The array is a 2D Array: arrAllYield(5,50)
    Set raArray = wksA.Cells.Find(What:=arrAllYield(1, iC - 1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
    :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
    False, SearchFormat:=False)
    If raArray Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox ("Not found")
    Else
        arrAllYield(3, iC - 1) = wksA.Cells(raArray.Row, raArray.Column + 12) 
        arrAllYield(4, iC - 1) = wksA.Cells(raArray.Row, raArray.Column + 26)
        Exit For 'Exit the loop after the first match is found
    End If
Next iC
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but wouldnt that just exit out of the for-loop, w/o iterating through the other array elements, once a single match is found?

Comment: Maybe you want to have a look this link ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.findnext. So I think you need to do-loop for the findnext occurence inside the for-next loop.